# how paging Gridview with jquery?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I want use `jquery` for my `GridView control` like this demo : [Here](http://fooplugins.com/footable/demos/metro-theme.htm#demo)

I'm beginner in `jquery`, how can i use paging to my GridView like Demo?

**Here is my html:**

```
      <asp:GridView PageSize="5"   OnPreRender="gvListCash_PreRender"   CssClass="footable" AllowPaging="true"  Width="100%" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3"   ID="gvListCash"  RowStyle-Wrap="false" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="id"  >
               <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="id" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="name" SortExpression="name" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="type" HeaderText="type" SortExpression="type" />
                      <asp:BoundField DataField="price" HeaderText="price" SortExpression="price" />


                </Columns>

         </asp:GridView>

<script type="text/javascript">
         $(function () {
             $('table').footable();

             $('.colour-switch a').click(function (e) {
                 e.preventDefault();
                 $('.colour-switch a').each(function () {
                     $('table').removeClass($(this).data('class'));
                 });
                 $('table').addClass($(this).data('class'));
             });
         });
 </script>
```

**Here is my project demo image:**
[image]

i set  `PagerStyle-CssClass="pagination pagination-centered"` for my gridview but it doesn't work true !

Answer (score 0):

U can use the below link, its perfectly simple and logically nice to use.

http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Paging-in-ASPNet-GridView-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx